# Issues with quadratic programming

Tags: matlab, quadratic

I am trying to do a quadratic programming. I have an affinity matrix `A`, and I have to maximize certain function `x'*A*x`. This is basically related to feature matching i.e., matching points to labels

This is basically related to establish a connection between dominant sets in a weighted graph and local maximizers of the quadratic function

```
maximize(f({x} = x^{T}A{x})
```

subject to

```
x \epsilon\Delta, \Delta:\sum_{j}x_j=1
```

To solve this problem I found a method called replicator equation given by Pavan and Pelillo IEEE PAMI 2007

Once an initialization `x(1)` is given, the discrete replicator equation can be used to obtain a local solution x<sup>*</sup>

```
x_i(t+1) = x_i(t+1) \frac{(Ax(t))_i}{x(t)^TAx(t)}
```

I get the right results when I use the replicator equation. However, when I try to solve it using matlab's quadprog function like this

```
X = quadprog(-A,[],[],[],Aeq,Beq,s);
```

I don't get the right values. Suppose I want to match 7 points with 7 labels, I define my affinity matrix and then use the above. However, using replicator equation I get the right results. But using just quadprog doesn't give me the right results. Any suggestions?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Note that quadratic programming only works if the problem is convex, equivalently, if `A` is positive (semi-)definite.

Comment: Unfortunately, LaTeX formatting doesn't work here; that only works on math exchange, physics exchange, etc. SO should really enable it IMO, but for now, you'll have to use Unicode, HTML, etc. or upload an image of your rendered equations...

Answer (score 1):

`quadprog()` documentation shows:

```
x = quadprog(H,f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,x0)
```

`A` and `b` can be `[]` if there are no inequality constraints, but it does not say that about `f`, so I am assuming you should set `f` to be a `zeros` vector. Also, if what you marked as `s` is your initialization, then it isn't located in the correct position.

The line your wrote as:

```
X = quadprog(-A,[],[],[],Aeq,Beq,s);
```

should be:

```
X = quadprog(-A,f,[],[],Aeq,Beq,[],[],s);
```

where `f` is a zeros vector.

BTW if this is convex you shouldn't need the initialization point, and if it is not convex, I am not sure you can be guaranteed to find the same local solution as the replicator method.

Comment: Actually this is not true if A is positive semi-definite: the maximization problem becomes concave.

Answer (score 1):

If A is positive-semidefinite, then the maximization problem is a concave problem rather than a convex one. If A is negative semidefinite, then -A is positive semidefinite. You can just optimize x^T(-A)x in matlab.

Namely:

```
min x^TAx
```

is convex,

and

```
max x^TAx  =  min x^T(-A)x
```

is concave.

if

```
A>0 (Positive semidefinite)
```

And quadprog needs convex

Since matlab quadprog fails, I guess your A is positive semidefinite. You can do eig(A) to check if all eigen values are positive, thus you need some concave optimization solution.

Comment: yes the function is not convex. So how can I optimize it other than using the replicator equation